# Как из одной формы отправить два post запроса?

Tags: php

Имеется форма для заполнения и кнопка отправить, нужно данные из этой формы отправить в два разных места, один для сохранения данных на сервере, другой для генерации и скачивания документа в котором будут введенные данные содержаться. Так вот, как можно сделать это?
Сейчас отправляется вот так:

```
<form action="nko-word.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> или так <form action="nko.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Хотелось бы разом это все отправить

Comment: Так, а кто вам мешает на стороне сервера переслать данные на хранение? А так - подцепляете js на обработку и отправляете хоть в сто мест

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Объединить два скрипта в один и уже его указывать в параметрах формы
2. Использовать AJAX и отправлять либо один, либо оба запроса через AJAX
3. В одном из скриптов сделать обращение ко второму через POST запрос - это в том случае если скрипты находятся на разных доменах/серверах. Т.е. некий прокси для запроса
4. Сделать две формы. Сделать их невидимыми, а обращение к скриптам делать в iframe. При этом отправку форм сделать через JS. В общем-то это сильно упрощенный аналог 2-го пункта.